# php создает две сессии вместо одной при попытке коннекта к базе

Tags: php, postgresql

Уважаемые, подскажите пожалуйста, почему при попытке pg_connect (неважно, успешной или неуспешной) php создает две сессии - одну пустую, а вторая - собственно, моя рабочая. Работаю на openserver под винду 10. Наипростейший код ниже. Стоит закомментировать строку коннекта - при загрузке страницы стартует одна сессия, как и положено.

```
     session_start();

     $sql_host = "host";
     $sql_port = "5432";
     $sql_dbname = "basename";
     $sql_login = "login";
     $sql_password = "password";

     $db = pg_connect("host=".$sql_host." port=".$sql_port." dbname=".$sql_dbname." user=".$sql_login." password=".$sql_password);
```

Comment: "Стоит закомментировать строку коннекта - при загрузке страницы стартует одна сессия, как и положено" значит где-то еще происходит один коннект. Иначе при комментировании не было бы никакой сессии. Голый скрипт или фреймворк используется?

Comment: Нет! специально убрал все, в директории единственный файл index.php с кодом, который я выше разместил!

Comment: Это реакция именно на вызов функции pg_connect. Допускаю что Openserver может что- то там мудрить, но хотелось бы услышать мнение людей

Comment: Такое впечатление, что там настроено хранение сессий в постгре и это собственно реакция на session_start

Comment: Закрыл браузер, рестартанул опенсервер - глюк исчез, хотя при открытом браузере он оставался, несмотря на рестарт! Нажимаю "Обновить" - хоп! - две сессии стартанули! Еще раз "Обновить" - хоп - еще одна! Причем проверяю - скрипты устойчиво видят и работают с правильной сессией, а пустые просто тусуются рядом пока их уборщик не грохнет. Непонятка какая то. Спишу на выкаблучивания опенсервера. Спасибо за участие!